# appium not typing keys on password field Python

Tags: python-3.x, appium-android

I am trying to automate an android app using appium and python, that app requires login, send_keys() to email type input works fine, but it doesn't send keys to password type input, doesn't throw any error but password field remains empty. I have made it click on the element before typing, and the click works fine it clicks on the element but doesn't type in any characters,
adding my code bellow.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('com.offerup:id/password').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id('com.offerup:id/password').send_keys('nnnj')
```

Bellow I am adding the source of the page :

```
[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><hierarchy rotation="0"><android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[0,0\]\[1080,2076\]" resource-id="" instance="0"><android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[0,0\]\[1080,2076\]" resource-id="" instance="0"><android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[0,72\]\[1080,2076\]" resource-id="" instance="1"><android.view.ViewGroup index="0" text="" class="android.view.ViewGroup" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[0,72\]\[1080,2076\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/decor_content_parent" instance="0"><android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[0,72\]\[1080,240\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/action_bar_container" instance="2"><android.view.ViewGroup index="0" text="" class="android.view.ViewGroup" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[0,72\]\[1080,240\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/action_bar" instance="1"><android.widget.ImageButton index="0" text="" class="android.widget.ImageButton" package="com.offerup" content-desc="Navigate up" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[0,72\]\[168,240\]" resource-id="" instance="0"/><android.widget.TextView index="1" text="Log in" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[216,122\]\[370,189\]" resource-id="" instance="0"/></android.view.ViewGroup></android.widget.FrameLayout><android.widget.FrameLayout index="1" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[0,240\]\[1080,2076\]" resource-id="android:id/content" instance="3"><android.widget.ScrollView index="0" text="" class="android.widget.ScrollView" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[0,240\]\[1080,2076\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/login_detail_scrollview" instance="0"><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[0,240\]\[1080,2076\]" resource-id="" instance="0"><android.widget.ImageView index="0" text="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[157,360\]\[922,627\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/profile_picture" instance="0"/><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="1" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[48,723\]\[1032,975\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/emailaddress" instance="1"><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[48,723\]\[1032,975\]" resource-id="" instance="2"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="EMAIL ADDRESS" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[48,723\]\[383,771\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/title" instance="1"/><android.widget.FrameLayout index="1" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[48,795\]\[1032,927\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/edit_text_container" instance="4"><android.widget.EditText index="0" text="frankmlaverty@yahoo.com" class="android.widget.EditText" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="false" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[48,795\]\[1032,927\]" resource-id="" instance="0"/></android.widget.FrameLayout></android.widget.RelativeLayout></android.widget.RelativeLayout><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="2" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[48,975\]\[1032,1227\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/password" instance="3"><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[48,975\]\[1032,1227\]" resource-id="" instance="4"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="PASSWORD" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[48,975\]\[293,1023\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/title" instance="2"/><android.widget.FrameLayout index="1" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[48,1047\]\[1032,1179\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/edit_text_container" instance="5"><android.widget.EditText NAF="true" index="0" text="" class="android.widget.EditText" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[48,1047\]\[1032,1179\]" resource-id="" instance="1"/><android.widget.TextView index="1" text="Hide" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[848,1053\]\[1032,1172\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/password_hide_show" instance="3"/></android.widget.FrameLayout></android.widget.RelativeLayout></android.widget.RelativeLayout><android.widget.TextView index="4" text="Forgot your password?" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[296,1263\]\[783,1352\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/reset_password" instance="4"/><android.widget.LinearLayout index="5" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[0,1352\]\[1080,2076\]" resource-id="" instance="1"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="By logging in, you agree to the OfferUp Terms of Service and Privacy Policy." class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[0,1732\]\[1080,1826\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/tos_privacy" instance="5"/><android.view.View index="1" text="" class="android.view.View" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[0,1862\]\[1080,1865\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/divider" instance="0"/><android.widget.LinearLayout index="2" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[48,1901\]\[1032,2040\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/action_button" instance="2"><android.view.ViewGroup index="0" text="" class="android.view.ViewGroup" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[84,1937\]\[996,1998\]" resource-id="" instance="2"><android.widget.CheckedTextView index="0" text="Log in" class="android.widget.CheckedTextView" package="com.offerup" content-desc="" checkable="true" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="\[469,1937\]\[611,1998\]" resource-id="com.offerup:id/main_text" instance="0"/></android.view.ViewGroup></android.widget.LinearLayout></android.widget.LinearLayout></android.widget.RelativeLayout></android.widget.ScrollView></android.widget.FrameLayout></android.view.ViewGroup></android.widget.FrameLayout></android.widget.LinearLayout></android.widget.FrameLayout></hierarchy>][1]
```

Comment: Can you try with send_keys(“nnnj”) instead send_keys(‘nnnj’)